# python passing cookies to header issue

Tags: python, cookies, header

What i need is to extract uid cookie from the first web site and open the second one with it (it's a sort of authorisation)

it neither works with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
import socket, Cookie
def extract(url):
 jar = cookielib.FileCookieJar("cookies")
 opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
 opener.addheaders = [('User-agent',
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20110201 Firefox/2.0.0.14')]

 response = opener.open(url)
 for cookie in jar:
    precious_value = cookie.value
 return precious_value

site1 = "mysite1.com"
site2 = "mysite2.com"

cp = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()
cj = cp.cookiejar
cj.set_cookie(cookielib.Cookie(0, cookie_name, 
                               extract(site1), 
                               '80', False, 'domain', True, False, '/path',
                               True, False, None, False, None, None, None))
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler(),cp)
opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible)'))
print opener.open(site2).read()
```

nor this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
def extract(url):
 jar = cookielib.FileCookieJar("cookies")
 opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
 opener.addheaders = [('User-agent',
   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20110201 Firefox/2.0.0.14')]

 response = opener.open(url)
 for cookie in jar:
    precious_value = cookie
 return precious_value 

site1 = "mysite1.com"
site1 = "mysite2.com"

jar = cookielib.FileCookieJar("cookies")
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; 
en-GB; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20110201 Firefox/2.0.0.14')]

opener.addheaders = [('Cookies', extract(site1))]
response = opener.open(site2)
print response.read()
```

however I've managed to succeed here with 'requests' library
the code looks nice:

```
cookies= dict(mycid='9ti6cACUi6AqxXBG2H9AMPkrfRbBJPalKTAh_bLcuQ8c8C')
r = requests.get(url, cookies = cookies)
print r.text
```

Its fine for me and I don't have anything against requests... but still what have i done wrong during two first attempts? In both cases extract procedures work fine and I see that uid has been properly extracted. I guess the problem is with add_headers area. The answer is obvious but still can get through. Can someone help?

1) What is the proper way to pass a cookie into headers only with urllib or urllib2?

2) How can I pass it as a parameter which can be changed, not just reference to extracted object?

3)How should I properly pass it as an object name/value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer to your question #1 is exactly the reason why `requests` exists.  It's not that you necessarily did something wrong or can't comprehend the "right" way to do it in Python, it's that Python's HTTP handling is broken.  `requests` fixes it, and is really how it should have been in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop `def extract(url):` has two problems:

1. It always returns the last value, which is not necessarily where you cookie is
2. It makes assumption on the order in which cookie are store which you can't know

(i'm assuming `precious_value`  is defined somewhere else otherwise this code doesn't work)

To know which key you should use to retrieve the particular cookie you're interested in, you can use chrome developer tools to see what's the name of the cookie set by the site you want.

Hope this helps.